# Navigation in Single App Application using google.script.history.setChangeHandler fails after refreshing the page (returns a blank screen)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, iframe, html5-history

**DESCRIPTION:**
When using "google.script.history.push" and "google.script.history.setChangeHandler" to create a Single Page Application (SPA), a blank screen is returned when navigating using "Back/Forward" browser buttons. But ONLY after a page refresh.  If the user doesn't refresh the page, everything works as intended. It just fails when the user refreshes the page.  I could recreate the problem in Google Chrome (Desktop and Mobile) and the MS Edge browsers.  However, it worked properly when I used Samsung's Mobile Browser.  This is not a big issue for desktop users as they will rarely refresh when navigating through the app.  However, mobile users can often accidently refresh a page when swiping up or down and reaching the end of the page, thus causing the page to refresh.  Mobile users will often inadvertently end up with a blank white page.

I included the sample Google Apps Script code below to be able to re-create the problem.

**STEPS TO RE-CREATE PROBLEM**

1. Open GAS app in Browser.  You should see a blue box with 2 buttons.
2. Click the "Show Red ONLY" button.  You should now see the red box.
3. Click the "Show Blue ONLY" button.  You should now see the blue box.
4. Click your browser's "back" button.  You should see the red box as intended.  So far so good.
5. Click your browser's "forward" button.  Everything is still fine as you should see the blue box again.
6. Click on your browser's "refresh" button.   Still good as the blue box is still displayed based on the URL's "Color" parameter.
7. This is where the BUG shows its face.  Click on your browser's "back" button.  You would EXPECT to see the red box.  However, you end up with a blank screen.

Navigating forward or backwards through the app using the browser's "Back" and "Forward" buttons works fine only as long as the user DOESN'T refresh the page.  As I mentioned, on Samsung's Mobile Browser, the app worked fine.  So depending on the browser you use, the bug may or may not happen.

**GOOGLE SERVER SCRIPT CODE:**

```
    function doGet(e){
        let htmltemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Home.html");
        let htmloutput = htmltemplate.evaluate();
        return htmloutput;
    }//END FUNCTION
```

**HTML CODE (Home.html):**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <base target="_top">
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="showRed();">Show Red ONLY</button>
        <button onclick="showBlue();">Show Blue ONLY</button>
        <div id="Red" style="width:200px; height: 200px; background-color:red;">Red Square</div>
        <div id="Blue" style="width:200px; height: 200px; background-color:blue;">Blue Square</div>

    <script>
        function showRed(){
        let now = new Date();
        let state = {"timestamp": now.getTime()};
        let params = {"Color": "Red"};
        google.script.history.push(state, params);
        renderPage();
        }

        //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
       function showBlue(){
       let now = new Date();
       let state = {"timestamp": now.getTime()};
       let params = {"Color": "Blue"};
       google.script.history.push(state, params);
       renderPage();
       }

       //DISPLAY proper box based off the URL's "Color" parameter
       function renderPage(){
       google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
       strColor = location.parameter.Color;
                
       if(strColor === "Red"){
       document.getElementById("Red").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("Blue").style.display = "none";
       }else{
       document.getElementById("Red").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("Blue").style.display = "block";
       }
       });
    } //END function


    //CHANGE HANDLER
    google.script.history.setChangeHandler(function (e) {
      renderPage()
});

    
    //EVENT LISTENER TO RENDER PAGE
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', renderPage());

    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#web_apps_and_browser_history)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that doc.  As I explained, it works as intended as long as the user doesn't refresh the page.  A page refresh by the user shouldn't cause what it's causing.  It looks like a BUG.

Comment: If you think it's a bug then report it as an issue to google

Comment: No errors are thrown.

Comment: I have reported the issue to Google.  I was just wondering if anybody else had this problem or could reproduce it with the sample code I included.

Comment: Reproducible on chrome. You may add the issue tracker link as a answer. You may try examining the [history object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) in the browser console/remote debugging

Comment: Bug was reported on Google's Issue Tracker.  
Issue ID: 207785211
Issue URL:  https://issuetracker.google.com/207785211

Answer (score 0):

This was reported to Google issue tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/207785211 If you're affected by this issue, add a star to this issue by clicking the star icon on top left.

Comment: Answer posted as community post. Anyone may freely edit this post whenever required.